# Excel is duplicating part of my formula when moving sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate

Help please, I have a spreadsheet I created and use it to attach to other workbooks that has formulas to pull data from other sheets within the newly attached workbook. Problem is that when I open my workbook and copy my worksheet excel then duplicates the page reference and puts the duplicated part in brackets [] then my formulas no longer know what page to pull the info from.

Example; my formula is `=('Combined Master'!C5)` so that this sell can pull the info from `C5` of sheet Combined Master. However once I attach this spreadsheet to my workbook excel then re-writes my formula to `('[Combined Master]Combined Master'!C5)` and I then have to go to every cell having to erase the `[Combined Master]`.

Is there some way to stop excel from changing/duplicating the reference page?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: adding info so there is less confusion.

Comment: so I don't confuse everyone.  =('Combined Master'!C5) is from my template sheet I use to add each time to different workbook containing different information. But when Im adding my templet sheet to a new workbook the templet sheet that was added then changes to ('[Combined Master]Combined Master'!C5) automatically so the cell with this formula does not know what page of the workbook to pull from because its been duplicated by excel. I then have to go to all my cells that have formulas that were supposed to pull information from the other pages in the workbook and remove the "[Combined Master]"

Comment: To be strictly correct, the [Combined Master] (in square brackets) that Excel is adding to the formula is the name of your "template" workbook - so, when you're copying the sheet to another workbook, the reference remains back to the original workbook where the sheet was copied from.  To be honest, I think your only option would be to create some VBA that will look through all of the cells and amend the formulas accordingly.  (There certainly don't appear to be any options available when copying the sheet to another workbook, so Excel is just doing what it believes is correct)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend including a blank sheet when you attach your "template" (functional/established) sheet to its new application (i.e., the new workbook). The blank sheet will serve as a reference for your functional sheet in the new workbook. Then paste the values (the "different information" you refer to) of the sheet you want to be acted upon by your functional sheet.

to add the functional sheet and the blank reference sheet to the new workbook, select the functional sheet and the reference using ctrl key and selecting the sheet tabs, then choose Move/Copy Sheets to append them to the new workbook where you would like them to act.

Comment: Also, if you don’t favor the solution, then I recommend noting that Find & Replace works in formulas, so you would not have to erase every instance of the bracketed Worksheet name as you have described.